# inject javascript in head or body

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-mvc-4

In the file index.cshtml  I need to inject JavaScript code, we developed the helper that is a library call in .net to load the JavaScript code that is in the dll .. We are doing this for safety reasons.
The Helper code to call this function ToolBarControl the dll calls the next method I attached a piece of code.

```
private string RenderBarra() {
    StringBuilder JavaScript = new StringBuilder();
    JavaScript.AppendFormat(@"<script type= ""text/javascript"">{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    JavaScript.AppendFormat(@"var toolbar = new toolBarObject('toolbarObj');{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    ...
    ...
    JavaScript.AppendFormat(@"</script>{0}", Environment.NewLine);
    return JavaScript.ToString();
}
```

Html.ToolBarControl calling function to inject the script places the top (before of html head) I need to make this code in the header is injected into the head, body of the page or at the end

Note: the code javascript in the method RenderBarra works

Comment: just use the Section feature to specify where code will be rendered:

Comment: http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2010/12/30/asp-net-mvc-3-layouts-and-sections-with-razor.aspx

Comment: Thiago I use section but i can't load the method RederBarra in the section I write this:

Comment: Sorry, I didn't understand. You must put this code in a controller action and then call the RenderAction inside a section in your View.

Answer (score 3):

Just create a simple html helper that will render the string 
Example:
Html.RenderBarra()

Don't forget to render it as Raw text(@Html.Raw(your_helper))